# Matlab on Ubuntu stuck at `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:`

Tags: java, matlab, ubuntu

I want to open Matlab without `cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin` and the `sudo ./matlab`.

So I `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc` and write the following commands in the ending:

```
export MATLAB_ROOT="/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin"

if [ -d "${MATLAB_ROOT}" ]; then
   export PATH="${PATH}:${MATLAB_ROOT}"
fi
```

After `source ~/.bashrc` and I use `echo $PATH` to see that the path of matlab does exist. But when I use `matlab` to open the it, it will be stuck at `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:` whereas `cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin` and the `sudo ./matlab` commands work well.

And if I directly use `sudo ./matlab`, it will show `sudo：./matlab: command not found`

Other information: `which java` shows `/usr/bin/java`

`unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` will cause another error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found the problem, I use the command `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin` or `unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, and then get the error as follows.

[image]

It makes me recall the `sudo` command, so it might be a problem of permission right. Since I have to open Matlab without leaving that directory, I use `ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/matlab /path/to/your/current` and then `sudo ./matlab`. It works.

But how to really solve this problem remains unknown. The other methods I saw like `sudo apt-get remove jayatana` and `sudo rm /usr/share/upstart/sessions/jayatana.conf` may cause unpredictable result, so I could not try them.